# How to get the response from AWS to localhost client?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, rest

If my application is running on AWS as ECS containers and it will be sending the response back to the url which we will be passing it as a solution url . My question is if we are passing localhost (client is running on local machine ) url in solution url , which network configurations we need to change to get the response back ?

Comment: That is not going to work since your local client is not reachable form the internet unless you set it up in a special way. Is your local client connected to the VPC e.g. using a VPN?

Comment: No @luk2302 , it is not connected to the VPC . Is there any way we can connect and get the response back . And also will it be the same way if the client is in on premise.

Comment: You need to bind your client to your machine's actual ip (I've used `-B 0.0.0.0` on Wildfly, not sure what framework you're using) and use that ip in the callback. However, that still might require some more setup, e.g. if you're using NAT etc. - it all depends on your environment. "Will it be the same way if the client is in on premise." - it might be a different network configuration since the on premise network might be different but binding the application to the mchine's external IP address should work the same. Always make it configurable in any case.

Comment: And all firewalls in between need to be configured to let the request through...

Comment: You could conceivably set up a redirection on your AWS-based application to tell it that localhost should redirect to some real URL, probably just an IP address.  However, that would mean you'd have to set up your developer's machine to be targetable from the outside by that IP address.  Then what's going to happen if another developer hits the AWS application?  It's going to send the response to the one it's been told localhost redirects to.  From your response to luk2302, I suspect a better solution is to have the clients poll for when the data is ready rather than to use a webhook.

Answer (score 0):

That will never work.

You're passing a solution URL to the application in AWS and you're expecting it to answer to that URL. Basically AWS will use a DNS Server to resolve the given URL and it will send a response to the given IP.

If you send `localhost` as URL to AWS, it will try to resolve it as well, but since `localhost` is already defined in `/etc/hosts` as `127.0.0.1`, it will just directly send the request to itself.

You can do what you want, but it's going to be a little bit more messy than just sending an URL.

First of all, you need to configure your router to forward all the incoming traffic from internet to that client that you're talking about. Afterwards, you'd require to check which is the public IP of your machine and provide that to the AWS service.

For example, let's suppose that I'm using that aforementioned AWS service and I have already configured my router so all the incoming requests to the public IP are redirected to my machine in an arbitrary port (5000 for example).

1. I need to acquire my public IP, one easy way would be by a GET request to `ifconfig.me`
2. I provide that URL to the AWS Container, for example by PathParams: [https://myawscontainer.aws.com/serviceA?solutionURL=[HERE_GOES_MY_IP]](https://myawscontainer.aws.com/serviceA?solutionURL=%5BHERE_GOES_MY_IP%5D)
3. After the task in the container is done, the AWS Container would request to [HERE_GOES_MY_IP]:80, or any other port, depending on how have you configured the container to perform the requests afterwards.
4. If I have configured my router to forward any request in the port 80 to my machine in the port 5000, I'll receive the AWS request on my local machine on the configured port.

Of course you could get a domain pointing to your public IP if that one is static, or even set up dynamic DNS within the router with Open Source solutions as `pfSense`.